# How to insert current date time in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know of a way that I can insert the current date & time in a visual studio code by snippets?

I have looked docs but did not get any information about it.

I want to create a snippets like this：

```
title: theFileTitle
date: 2016-08-05 09:44:16
```

Comment: the question is vague, please explain in more detail

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I have created an extension for you that allows to insert formatted date and/or time string - [Insert Date String](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jsynowiec.vscode-insertdatestring).

**Installation**

Open Command Palette by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `ext install` + press `Enter` and then look for **Insert Date String** extension.

**Usage**

To insert current date and/or time at the cursor position you can:

Press <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (OS X) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (Windows and Linux), or open **Command Palette** by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> and type `Insert DateTime` then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**Configuration**

By default you don't have to set anything. But if you want to change the datetime format, look for `insertDateString.format` option in user settings.

```
// Date format to be used.
"insertDateString.format": "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss",
```

You can specify any valid ISO 8601 format. There are some [examples in readme](https://github.com/jsynowiec/vscode-insertdatestring#examples).

**Snippet**

Unfortunately you can't use anything more than tab stops or variables in snippets so you'll have to enter the title and date/time manually.

You can [define snippets for specific languages](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/userdefinedsnippets#_creating-your-own-snippets). To open a snippet file for editing, open `User Snippets` under `File > Preferences (Code > Preferences on Mac OS X)` and select the language for which the snippets should appear.

*Following example is for Plain Text files.*

After opening a snippet file for Plain Text, add following definition:

```
{
     "File header": {
        "prefix": "header",
        "body": [
            "title: ${title:Enter title}",
            "date: ${date:Insert datetime string (⇧⌘I or Ctrl+Shift+I)}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Now you can open a new plaintext file, enter `header` and press `Tab`. Enter your title and use `Insert DateTime` command to insert current date and/or time.

[image]

**Idea for a more customizable solution**

One could write an extension for inserting such headers. This way some sort of templates with several predefined variables (e.g. date, filename, configurable username/email, etc.) might be used.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sadly, CTRL + SHIFT + I conflicts with VSCode code formatting.

Comment: @FrederikKrautwald you can always remap it or use through command palette. `⌃+⇧+I` was not present on the Windows keybindings list when I published it.

Comment: Related info: The extension vscode-fileheader inserts author name, creation date, modification date etc. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mikey.vscode-fileheader

Comment: Where do you edit the shortcut key for this?

Comment: It seems that this extension could be deprecated due to built-in [snippet variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_more-snippet-variables) functionality mentioned by other people here.

Answer (score 90):

As of Jan 2018 (release 1.20) you can use [these new snippet environment variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_more-snippet-variables).

Your example above would look like this:

```json
"File Header": {
    "prefix": "header",
    "description": "Output a file header with the file name and date",
    "body": [
        "title: $TM_FILENAME",
        "date: $CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND",
    ]
}
```

Type `head`, press `ctrl+space` and it should [show snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables) menu.

Comment: FYI if you don't see the time it is because you have to remove the new line between the date and time formatting.

Comment: @Robert This is not necessarily better than the accepted solution. While a "native" solution is preferred when available, it lacks some functionality -- for example, I needed the three-letter day name, which is not possible using this method.

Comment: Neither was it the OPs question, right? Referring to the actual question, I prefer this answer over the accepted one. Still the accepted one is absolutely right and apparently still convinced the majority of readers. I'm happy seeing both ways here - wonderful free world ;)

Answer (score 62):

if you don't want create a snippet, there is a simple way,  using keybindings.

open keybindings.json (Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)), and add fellow code to your keybindings.json

```
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+k t",
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
        "args": {
            "snippet": "$CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND"
        }
    }
]
```

that's all.

now you can use `cmd+k t` to insert current data time while typing.

Comment: Aaargh.. Remember to replace `cmd` with `ctrl` on Windows.

Comment: Other variable options found at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables

Answer (score 6):

You can just use the following variables in your snippets:

```
$CURRENT_YEAR
$CURRENT_YEAR_SHORT
$CURRENT_MONTH
$CURRENT_DATE
$CURRENT_HOUR
$CURRENT_MINUTE
$CURRENT_SECOND
```

Links to the official VSCode docs:
[date and time in snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_20#_more-snippet-variables)
[user defined snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets)

Answer (score 3):

The env variable `TM_FILENAME` will fill the title with the file name automatically.

For example:

```
"title: ${1:$TM_FILENAME_BASE}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a tool outside of Code, like for example [Texter](https://lifehacker.com/238306/lifehacker-code-texter-windows).
I have configured it to replace `[t` with `[%ds %t]`, which gives me [9/11/2017 16:30] while I type, regardless of application.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74082031/836330 for how to insert the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` timeStamp with options with a keybinding:

[image: adding a time stamp with padding]

---

Or see [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) extension.  It uses the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` format and can be used in a keybinding like so:

```
 {
    "key": "alt+d",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "extension.commandvariable.dateTimeInEditor",

    "args": {
      "locale": "en-US",
      "options": {
        "year": "numeric",
        "month": "long",
        "weekday": "long",
        "day": "2-digit",
        "hour12": false,
        "hour": "2-digit",
        "minute": "2-digit",
        "second": "2-digit"
      },
      "template": "${month} ${day}, (${weekday}), ${year} - ${hour}:${minute}::${second}"
    }
  },
```

to produce

`March 25, (Wednesday), 2020 - 21:16::49`

and many other timestamp versions.  See the possibilities at [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit of an overkill but you can check [`Org Mode` extension](https://github.com/vscode-org-mode/vscode-org-mode) which has this functionality and more:

[image: Org Mode change date gif]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet for Vscode, I used to refer to this in my code files.

```json
"file description": {
  "prefix": "template",
  "body": [
    "\"\"\"",
    "# _* coding: utf8 *_",
    "",
    "filename: $TM_FILENAME",
    "",
    "@author: sounishnath",
    "createdAt: $CURRENT_YEAR-$CURRENT_MONTH-$CURRENT_DATE $CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND",
    "\"\"\"",
    "",
    ""
  ],
  "description": "file description"
}
```

Comment: you can set up as a global snippet in vs code. and just type `template` - as a prefix for generating the snippet. 