# vscode insert date time each new line?

Tags: date, time, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I would like to (ab)use vscode as a tool for some specific live-logging.
For this purpose I would like to have it insert the current date, time at the beginning of each line. I did look here: [How to insert current date time in vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780057/how-to-insert-current-date-time-in-vscode) but it only goes half-way there. I have only recently moved from Atom to VScode and am a bit daunted by trying to do this from first principles - any pointers would be most welcome!

As a bonus: if this function could be created so that it only takes place in files which have been saved with a specific file extension, that would be even more awesome! Otherwise I need to turn on/off this feature every time I use VScode for something else...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) put this into your settings:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.insertTimeonNewline",

    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.insertLineAfter",        
      {
        "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
        "args": {
          "snippet": "$CURRENT_HOUR:$CURRENT_MINUTE:$CURRENT_SECOND  "
        }
      },
    ]  
  }
]
```

And this into keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "enter",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.insertTimeonNewline" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus && resourceExtname =~ /\\.php/"
},
```

Change that extension at the end of the when clause to whatever extension you need to use.

Now <kbd>Eenter</kbd> will enter a new line and put the time at the beginning of it.  You should modify the time variables if you want year, month, etc.

[image: insert time on newline demo]