# How to define a VScode snippet which pastes some texts by running a code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

In `RStudio`, there is a snippet as follows:

```
snippet ts
    `r paste("#", date(), "------------------------------\n")`
```

It will pastes some texts by running `date()`,
for example,
`# Sat Oct 15 11:04:22 2022 ------------------------------`.

---

**How to define this in `VScode`?**

Comment: with extension **Hypersnips** you can use JavaScript to create the content of the snippet

Comment: @rioV8 Thank you! I need this extension more. By the way, is it possible to run other language (like python or r) by this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this in any type of file.  You will need this extension (that I wrote), [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview).  Make this keybinding (in your `keybindings.json`):

```
{
  "key": "alt+d",
  "command": "findInCurrentFile",
  "args": {
    
    "replace": [
      "$${",
        "const date = new Date();",
        "const options = { weekday: 'short', month: 'short', year: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',  hour: 'numeric',  minute: 'numeric',  second: 'numeric'};",
        "let str = `${LINE_COMMENT} ` +  new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date) + ' ';",
        
        "return str.padEnd(70, '-');",    // padEnd with ---, whatever final length you want
        
      "}$$"
    ],
    "restrictFind": "line",
    "postCommands": "cancelSelection"
  },
  // "when": "editorLangId == r"
}
```

You can use any of the `Intl.DateTimeFormat` options.

Note the use of `${LINE_COMMENT}`  at the beginning of the string.  That will resolve to the comment style of whichever language you are in at the time.  The demo is in an `r` file.

[image: demo of keybinding to add a time stamp with comment and padding]

Answer (score 0):

With extension [File Templates](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.vscode-file-templates#insert-template-in-current-file) you can create a key binding that insert a template with date variables.

Create a date format you want and the template that uses that date format.